# Сервер Ubuntu на VM Oracle перестал слушать порт 5432 после попытки загрузить в БД большую таблицу

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

Загрузка таблицы закончилась ошибкой, но в результате потерял доступ к БД с сообщением "could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "192.168.56.101" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"
$ sudo netstat -pant дает

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1218/sshd
```

хотя в posgresql.conf прописано

```
listen_addresses = '*' 
port = 5432
```

Администрированием сервера специально не занимаюсь, так что могу не заметить чего-то очевидного, извиняюсь.

Comment: сервер мог упасть. надо убедится в наличии свободного места на диске, после этого смотреть логи сервера на предмет ошибок

Comment: @Mike места как раз и нет. И как его чистить, если нет доступа через порт 5432?

Comment: как-нибудь логиниться на сервер, чтобы-нибудь удалять (не из datadir базы), потом запускать базу. Или расширять место на дисках, потом запускать базу.

Comment: залогиниться не проблема по ssh. Но что значит "что-нибудь удалять"? здесь нужны определенные инструкции, наобум удалять - себе дороже.